"探しですか" vs "探しますか"
When asking the question of "what are you looking for", it appears that it should be "何を探しますか" and not "何を探しですか". Which aligns with what I understand, and is similar in structure to "何を食べますか" (what will you eat).
However, when looking at the polite form of the phrase (e.g. when asked by a shopkeeper to a customer), it seems that (according to a language learning app), on the contrary, it should be "何をお探しですか" and not "何をお探しますか".
Why is that so? Why whould the polite prefix "お" change the sentence structure?

「何を探しますか」 means "What do/will you look for?", not "What are you looking for?"

I have a feeling that you're thinking about this backward. The problem with a sentence that ends in a verb like 探す is that you can't use an honorific 御 with the verb. Thus, so that people could be more polite they nominalized the verb so that they could add the honorific. It's a peculiarity of this type of keigo that it still functions equivalently to a sentence ending in a verb because it's a special form of that type of sentence, not a sentence you're constructing from its base parts.

The grammar works fundamentally differently in the two examples.
In 何を探しますか, 探します is simply the polite form of 探す. "Do/will you look for something?" (As istrasci notes, the present continuous isn't appropriate for translation here; the equivalent would use te-iru form in Japanese.)
In 何をお探しですか, the i-stem 探し is being used like a noun. As far as I know, this doesn't see "ordinary" use outside of this special shopkeeper language, so it's hard to be sure of what it would mean, and thus harder to give a proper English translation that captures the grammatical structure. But I think it should be either "Is there a search for something?", or else "are you one who looks for something?". (Notice that with this framing, the simple present seems more natural in English.)
The honorific prefix 御 - pronounced お, おん or ご depending on what it attaches to, and usually written in kana - doesn't attach to verbs, except these i-stems. (That's more or less why the helper verb ます is necessary in the first place.)
For cultural reasons, shopkeepers are expected to say various things in especially polite and/or humble ways, and thus there are specific formulas they are expected to follow. By restructuring the sentence, the shopkeeper is able to add a second politeness marker (on top of using です rather than だ). This form, used in this case, is "honorific conjugation 2" in Tae Kim's guide.
If you aren't going to operate a shop yourself, you probably won't have to worry about these kinds of formulas, beyond recognizing basically what is being said. In a practical situation (i.e. you're actually in the bookstore and a shopkeeper is offering help), if you can pick out 何 and 探し from what you heard, the rest is not important.

hmmm... kind of get it, but in that case (i.e. with "お探し" being kind of like a noun), shouldn't the sentence structure then be "お探しは何ですか"?

It doesn't seem like 探し gets used as an "ordinary" noun, outside of ritual constructs like this one, so it's a bit hard to infer what meaning it would have. But I looked at this again and thought some more, and I think it must refer either to the act of searching (i.e. like Merlin said), or to the person who is searching. Please see the update.

(Updated again taking istrasci's comment into consideration.)

If I am not mistaken 探し is the nominalization of 探す.
In english it would translate to "The search".
I never wrapped my head around Keigo but it seems that "What is the search" rather than "what do you search" is considered more polite.
Here are two websites explaining the pattern お + stem + です.
https://yasuwangblog.com/odesu-en/
https://guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/honorific

The i-stem is used as a nominalization (there are other nominalized forms), but there isn't a consistent rule for what it means. I think 探し must refer to the searched-for thing, rather than the act of searching, because the sentence still says 何を rather than 何が.

Actually, I thought about it some more, and the fact that it says 何を is exactly why your interpretation makes more sense - I got confused.

その１つ目の「Yasuwangblog」っていうサイトの例文、間違いだらけですやん・・・「この案件は木村さんのご依頼です」「お元気ですか」「これはあの人のご質問です」は「お・ご〇〇だ・です」形の尊敬語じゃないですし、「一生のお頼みです」「古くから伝わってきたお遊びです」は日本語がおかしいですし。
